# irc subdomain set up

Tags: subdomain, irc

I have a question.
I want to make a sub domain to irc.*
To connect to a ircd server.
But i want to connect it to a other ip then my main ip number.
What should i do?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704709/how-to-create-a-subdomain-for-ircd

Answer (score 3):

Use the "DNS administraion interface" or similar provided by your ISP to create an A record on `irc.example.com` pointing on the IP of your IRCd server. If you have never done any DNS setup before, you might want to ask your ISP for help setting up the record (they might actually have a support section on their website describing how to do this yourself).